# How to extract certain words from R string?

Tags: r, stringr

I am relatively new to parsing data.

I have a dataset with the following sample text data that closely follows this format:

```
"Blessed to receive an offer from Texas State University." 
"Blessed to receive an offer from Columbia University."
```

What would be a good way to extract the school name after "from"?

I'm aware of stringr and pattern but can't seem to find a way to properly extract the variation in school names.

Comment: What have you tried that didn't work?

Comment: This seems like a good starting point: [Matching a word after another word in R regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34804708/matching-a-word-after-another-word-in-r-regex)

Comment: @camille I've tried using str_split_fixed(df$text, "from", 3) and str_split(df$text, "from")

Comment: And what about those didn't work? It's helpful to [edit] into your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `str_extract` (and assuming that all uni names are immediately followed by a period):

```
data <- c("Blessed to receive an offer from Texas State University.", 
          "Blessed to receive an offer from Columbia University.")
UniNames <- str_extract(data, "(?<=from\\s).*(?=\\.)")
```

Result:

```
UniNames
[1] "Texas State University" "Columbia University"
```

Comment: And if they are not followed by periods, what would be the best course of action?

Comment: That would change the picture drastically. Then, perhaps, this might help: `data <- c("Blessed to receive an offer from Texas State University.", 
          "Blessed to receive an offer from Columbia University.",
          "Blessed to receive an offer from Columbia University and other universities.")
str_extract(data, "(?<=from\\s)[A-Z]\\w+\\b\\s[A-Z]\\w+\\b(\\s[A-Z]\\w+\\b)?")`

Comment: For posterity, you can also do `str_match(data, "from\\s([A-Za-z\\s]+)")`.

Comment: @rpolicastro The result of the regex you suggest is not quite the desired matches: `str_match(data, "from\\s([A-Za-z\\s]+)")
     [,1]                                              [,2]                                        
[1,] "from Texas State University"                     "Texas State University"                    
[2,] "from Columbia University"                        "Columbia University"                       
[3,] "from Columbia University and other universities" "Columbia University and other universities"`

Comment: I was answering the original post. Didn't realize that he wanted matches that didn't end in periods.